# check does memcached store mysql queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli

Rails 3.2.18
memcached
dalli

I have added the line to **production.rb**

```
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store, '127.0.0.1', {:namespace => 'production'}
```

And I want that mysql queries will be stored in memcached.
How can I checked that queries are really in memcached.
Dump or something else?
All I found is `echo stats | nc 127.0.0.1 11211`
I would like to get text of mysql queries stored in memcached.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, sorry, i am not boss, just developer.